# Is there any way to use try/catch for the "view" functions?

Tags: solidity, try-catch

I have been trying to run this code:

```
function seeError(address _token) public view returns (uint256) {
        try IERC20(_token).decimals() {
            return IERC20(_token).decimals();
        } catch {
            revert("Error occured");
        }
    }
```

Now, since I can input any address for the token, I want to revert in case there are no decimals returned, or basically, the ERC20 address is wrong. So I tried using try/catch for this since I am unable to get the data directly. Is there any way to get the result I want? Try/catch is working for external calls only, can it work for `view` functions too?

Answer (score 1):

Why not do something like this

```
function seeError(address _token) public view returns (uint256) {
       (bool succes,) = _token.call(abi.encodePacked("decimals()"));
       require (success,"Error occured");
    }
```